# How to generate keystore for google play?

Tags: java, keystore

I am trying to generate keystore for my google account, so I can upload my application to google play.
I've type this both on jdk 1.07 and 1.06

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore C:\Android\uploader.keystore -alias uploader -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

and both result the same as this

```
keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Android\uploader.keystore (The system cannot find the path specified)

java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Android\uploader.keystore (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

I've googled to solve my problems, but there's no solution for:

```
The system cannot find the path specified
```

Could anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: you can create keystore easily from eclipse

Comment: @StinePike how to create it from eclipse? could you tell me?

Comment: while exporting an apk there is a option of keystore. There you can click create new keystore and create a new one

Comment: looks like you specified wrong option it should be  keytool -genkeypair (not -genkey) and this should automatically create the keystore. see the javadoc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html#Commands

Comment: @StinePike i am not using java to create my application, but using construct 2 then export to cocoon js to create apk.

Comment: @srikanthyaradla i tried to use -genkeypair, it didn't work same result..

Comment: May be you dont have permission to access that folder? What happens when you remove the -keystore option. Is it creating in your user home dir?

Comment: You can try to execute your command in administrator mode.

Comment: I know it's a stupid question, but do you have the folder "Android" in your C:? Because keytool isn't going to create it...

Comment: Succeed! Actually I locate the keystore on level 4 folder and it continuosly error. When I put it in first folder it worked!